# Listen to event on a node below window for an event sent to window

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I have some code that sent an event to `window`:

```
let toggleClicked = new Event("generic-toggle-clicked", {
  detail: { isActive: this.isActive },
});
document.dispatchEvent(toggleClicked, { bubbles: true });
```

I would like for an element other than `window` to listen to the event. Specifically, an element that's between `window` and the element dispatching the event (window > listener > event dispatcher). I have:

```
this.addEventListener("generic-toggle-clicked", function () {
  console.log(this);
});
```

Where this is the element I would like to listen to the event. However, even with `bubbles` set to `true`, it seems the element is not receiving the event.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that for an event to bubble up, it has to be dispatched to the innermost node, not the outermost one. So in the case above, this fixes it:

```
let toggleClicked = new Event("generic-toggle-clicked", {
  detail: { isActive: this.isActive },
});
this.dispatchEvent(toggleClicked, { bubbles: true });
```

and

```
this.addEventListener("generic-toggle-clicked", function () {
  console.log(this);
}, true);
```